# IBM MQ How do I know I have read all topics?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, mq

I have a dynamic topic tree on which the last message for each topic is "retained". When I subscribe to the topic tree (with JMS/Java/MQLibs), as it's dynamic and I am subscribing with the wildcard character "#", I cannot know what topics I will receive in advance. So,

1. How can I know when I have read all available topics at least once?
2. How can I know that the read topic is the original "retained" message that existed before I subscribed or is an update after subscription? (Do I need to keep a local map of MessageIDs against topics? I assume I cannot compare the time stamp of when I subscribed with the message creation time as the clock on the server and client may differ).

I have added some sample code, to show that I am accessing Topics not Queues.

```
public class JMSServerSubscriber implements MessageListener { 

public JMSServerSubscriber() throws JMSException { 
    TopicConnection topicCon = JmsTopicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection(); 
    TopicSession topicSes = topicCon.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); 
    Topic topic = topicSes.createTopic("#"); 
    TopicSubscriber topicSub = topicSes.createSubscriber(topic); 
    topicSub.setMessageListener(this); 
    topicCon.start(); 
} 

    @Override 
    public void onMessage(Message arg0) { 
            BytesMessage bm = (BytesMessage) arg0; 
            try { 
                    String destination = bm.getJMSDestination().toString(); 
            } catch (JMSException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
            }  
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. When you subscribe to a topic, you specify a queue into which MQ will put the messages published to that topic. When that queue is empty, you have read all the messages published to the topic. I don't see how subscribing to a part of the topic tree is different.

Comment: Lets says the actual topic tree looks like this; `/BusRoute/1` `/BusRoute/2`, and I subscribe to `/BusRoute/#`. I will get an immediate response for `1` and `2`, but how would I know that that is all there is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution using PCF. Please excuse any syntax errors.

```
public class TopicChecker implements MessageListener { 

    PCFMessageAgent           agent; 
    PCFMessage                pcfm; 
    Set<String>               allTopics; 
    TopicConnection           topicCon; 
    TopicSession              topicSes; 
    Topic                     topic; 
    TopicSubscriber           topicSub; 
    JmsTopicConnectionFactory jcf; 
    int                       total; 

    public TopicChecker() throws Exception { 
        allTopics = new HashSet<>(); 
        MQEnvironment.hostname = "myMqServer"; 
        MQEnvironment.channel = "MY.CHANNEL"; 
        MQEnvironment.port = 1515; 
        MQQueueManager m = new MQQueueManager("MY.QUEUE.MANAGER"); 
        agent = new PCFMessageAgent(m); 
        pcfm = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_INQUIRE_TOPIC_STATUS); 
        pcfm.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCA_TOPIC_STRING, "MyRoot/#"); 
        PCFMessage[] responses = agent.send(pcfm); 

        for (PCFMessage response: responses) { 
            /* We only publish to leaf nodes, so ignore branches. */
            if (response.getIntParameterValue(MQConstants.MQIACF_RETAINED_PUBLICATION) > 0) { 
            allTopics.add(response.getStringParameterValue(MQConstants.MQCA_TOPIC_STRING)); 
            } 
        } 

        total = allTopics.size(); 
        agent.disconnect(); 

        jcf = ...
        topicCon = jcf.createTopicConnection(); 
        topicSes = topicCon.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); 
        topic = topicSes.createTopic("MyRoot/#"); 
        topicSub = topicSes.createSubscriber(topic); 
        topicSub.setMessageListener(this); 
        topicCon.start(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onMessage(Message m) { 
     try { 
        String topicString = m.getJMSDestination().toString().replaceAll("topic://", ""); 
        allTopics.remove(topicString); 
        System.out.println("Read : " + topicString + " " + allTopics.size() + " of " + total + " remaining."); 
        if (allTopics.size() == 0) System.out.println("---------------------DONE----------------------"); 
        } catch (JMSException e) { 
               e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
       TopicChecker tc = new TopicChecker(); 
       while (tc.allTopics.size() != 0); 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When there are no more publications, the consumer.receive() method will throw an exception with MQRC 2033 reason code. You can use the reason code to confirm you have read all publications.

On the received message call getIntProperty(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_RETAIN); to know if the publication is retained or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. I though 2033 was for queue access, but I accessing topics (I know that Topics are really internal Queues). I have edited my question to include sample code.

Comment: Subscription will have a queue attached to which publications are put by MQ and your application receives messages from that queue. If message listener is used, the onMessage method will be called only when a message arrives on subscription queue. If there is no message, then onMessage method will not be called.

Comment: thanks for replying. I looked at the Message's header and see the `XMSC_WMQ_BROKER` variables which describe the underlying queues. However, when I open multiple JVMs with the same subscription, the internal queue names are the same in each JVM. So how do I identify my unique queue, or my individual subscription updates on a shared queue?

Comment: You don't need to worry about what queue is being used internally. MQ JMS client will pick the messages meant for your client application. Since you are using '#' you will get all publications.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know that I have read one example every topic that my subscription allows. Should I resort to PCF and query using `DISPLAY TPSTATUS ('myPath/#')` ? Is there a JMS way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

if (response.getIntParameterValue(MQConstants.MQIACF_RETAINED_PUBLICATION) > 0) { 
            allTopics.add(response.getStringParameterValue(MQConstants.MQCA_TOPIC_STRING)); 
            }

From the status response above, to read the topic name, you should actually use "MQCA_ADMIN_TOPIC_NAME".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please properly format code by indenting 4 spaces, and add a detailed explanation.